# Execution of a SP out of turn in a transaction

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net, transactions

SQL Server 2005 is used.

Each time a new data is received it is stored and a SP is called after that which uses this data to calculate some statistics data. Storing data and calling the SP is executed in a single transaction. The SP is enlisted in the transaction like

```
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    // ... executing insert/update statements ...

    var command = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedureName", connection);

    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", value));

    transaction.Enlist(command);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    transaction.Commit();
}
```

When running SQL Profiler I can see that all insert/update statements are shown there only after calling `transaction.Commit();` method but the SP call is shown immediately after calling `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` method. As a result the SP call is shown before insert/update statements in SQL Profiler. It makes me think that the SP is actually executed before any insert/update statements which is logically wrong.

The question is why the SP call is shown in SQL Profiler after calling `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` method and not `transaction.Commit();` one? Does it mean that it is executed immediately and not after executing insert/update statements?

Comment: What is the session and what type is the transaction?

Comment: NHibernate.ISession and usual explicit SQL transaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate session works like unit of work. All changes are stored in the session and they are persisted together only when you commit the transaction so you cannot use your procedure before you commit them because they haven't been stored in the database yet.

You must either do your computation in memory (if possible) or run your stored procedure after you commit transaction.

Comment: Thanks. This is the answer. I've found another option: call session.Flush() before calling the SP.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Profiler shows statements as they are executed.  Statements run with `ExecuteReader` and `ExecuteNonReader` are synchronous, so the insert/update statements would show before the procedure in SQL Profiler.

So looking for an explanation, how are you doing the insert/update statements?  Is it possible that you have a database layer that waits until `commit` before it starts sending out SQL to the server?

Comment: I use NHibernate: session.Save(entity), session.Update(entity). There is no database layer waiting until commit before it starts sending out SQL